# Calculate consecutive days a user log in per calendar date

Tags: sql, pyspark, data-analysis, databricks-sql

I need to calculate the number of consecutive logins for each of my user_id for each calendar_date using Databricks SQL. If I can't I could go for pyspark as well.

```
user_id  calendar_date         
    John    2022-01-01  
    John    2022-01-10
    Mary    2022-01-01
    Steve   2022-01-03
    Mary    2022-01-03
    John    2022-01-02
    John    2022-01-03
    Mary    2022-01-04
    John    2022-01-04
```

Output

```
  user_id  calendar_date consecutive_logins         
    John    2022-01-01          1
    John    2022-01-02          2
    John    2022-01-03          3
    John    2022-01-10          1
    Mary    2022-01-01          1
    Mary    2022-01-03          1
    Mary    2022-01-04          2
    Steve   2022-01-03          1
```

So far I've managed to come this far (but I'm stuck):

```
    WITH dau as (
select
  distinct
  concat_ws('-', year, month, day) as calendar_date,
  first_install_id as fiu
  
  
    FROM
        production.events
    WHERE 1=1
    
      and concat_ws('-', year, month, day) >= '2023-11-01'
     
),

sorted_logins AS (
    SELECT
        calendar_date,
        fiu,
        
       
        DATEDIFF(calendar_date, LAG(calendar_date) OVER (PARTITION BY fiu ORDER BY calendar_date)) AS days_since_last_login
from dau
),

consecutive_logins AS (
    SELECT
        calendar_date,
        fiu,
        
       
        SUM(CASE WHEN days_since_last_login = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY fiu ORDER BY calendar_date) AS consecutive_group
    FROM
        sorted_logins
) select * FROM consecutive_logins
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Databricks SQL version 2023.40 (very very similar to MySQL)

Comment: Databricks SQL and MySQL are not “*very similar*” to one another. They serve vastly different use cases and each has features the other does not, among many other differences. From where are you getting the idea to the contrary?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: @Paulb I've updated the initial post

Answer (score 0):

Your puzzle is like the cool old [Gaps & Islands problem](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9130/sql-server-window-functions-gaps-and-islands-problem/).
You can solve it by using the following SQL (MySQL) query:

```
with
  t1(user_id, calendar_date) as (
    values
      row('John' , '2022-01-01'),
      row('John', '2022-01-10'),
      row('Mary', '2022-01-01'),
      row('Steve', '2022-01-03'),
      row('Mary', '2022-01-03'),
      row('John', '2022-01-02'),
      row('John', '2022-01-03'),
      row('Mary', '2022-01-04')
  ),
  t2 as (
    select
      *,
      date_add(calendar_date,
               interval (-dense_rank()
                             over(partition by user_id
                                  order by calendar_date)) day) as island
    from t1
  )
select
  user_id, calendar_date,
  row_number()
    over(partition by user_id, island
         order by calendar_date) consecutive_logins
from t2;
```

This SQL query will yield the following:

```
+---------+---------------+--------------------+
| user_id | calendar_date | consecutive_logins |
+---------+---------------+--------------------+
| John    | 2022-01-01    |                  1 |
| John    | 2022-01-02    |                  2 |
| John    | 2022-01-03    |                  3 |
| John    | 2022-01-10    |                  1 |
| Mary    | 2022-01-01    |                  1 |
| Mary    | 2022-01-03    |                  1 |
| Mary    | 2022-01-04    |                  2 |
| Steve   | 2022-01-03    |                  1 |
+---------+---------------+--------------------+
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Na6f6jZ1xwp2ro3fsVTrd/0).